# Why the delay in ComboBox responding

Tags: javafx, combobox

Following code works, but when I change from Male to Female or vice versa, cbSpouse gets new Items loaded. Correct data gets loaded. But the issue is, if I click on the down arrow in cbSpouse, I need to wait for a few minutes before I see the drop down. There is no database interaction, all necessary data is already sitting in Observable list.

```
ObservableList<String> GenderOptions = FXCollections.observableArrayList("Male", "Female");
cbGender.getItems().clear();
cbGender.setItems(GenderOptions);
cbGender.setVisibleRowCount(GenderOptions.size());
cbGender.getSelectionModel().selectFirst();
cbGender.valueProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<String>() {
    @Override 
    public void changed(ObservableValue ov, String t, String t1) {
        System.out.println("Change Listener for cbGender - oldValue "+t+" new value"+t1);
        if ((t1.equals("Male")) || (t.equals(null))) {
            cbSpouse.setItems(myMainApp.getFemaleSpouses());
            if (thisPerson.getPhoto() == null) {
                thePicture.setImage(defaultMale);
            }
        } else {
            cbSpouse.setItems(myMainApp.getMaleSpouses());
            if (thisPerson.getPhoto() == null) {
                thePicture.setImage(defaultFemale);
            }
        }
        cbSpouse.getSelectionModel().selectFirst();
    }    
});
//
```

There are about 300 items in myMainApp.getMaleSpouses() which actually returns the Observable list.

Can someone help me?

Thanks in Advance.

Hornigold

Comment: I tried to create some working code that allows to reproduce the issue, assuming the data is already loaded, and it didn't work (assuming `thePicture` is a `ImageView` and it's not an issue here). Please add `getMaleSpouses` and `getFemaleSpouses` (or just one of them, if they are sufficiently similar). Also make sure to add any modifications to `cbSpouse` such as setting a `cellFactory` or adding a listener to the `value` property... (Create & post a [mcve].)

Comment: why don't you learn how to ask when you need debugging help (as already advised in your last question)? Incredible that you insist on wasting all our time ..

Comment: Hi Fabian, as you noticed ImageView is not a problem. But I cannot add the values in cellFactory for cbSpouse, because the values change based on value selected in another combo box cbGender. Issue is correct data is getting loaded in cbSpouse, but after a delay. I mean after changing cbGender from Male to Female, if you press the down arrow in cbSpouse nothing happens for a while. Tried disabling cbSpouse and enabling it before and after cbGender valueProperty change event. There are 299 male spouses and female spouses. FYI. Sorry for asking stupid questions.

Comment: Please note, that wrote a smaller version, where there are only 5 male and 5 female records, and they come in a jiffy.

Answer (score -1):

Here is the smaller version, which works nicely. Just keep changing the Gender and click on Spouses, new list appears.

```
package application;

import javafx.beans.property.IntegerProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleIntegerProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.StringProperty;
import javafx.scene.control.Tooltip;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;

/**
 *
 * @author Hornigold Arthur
 */
public class APerson {

    private final StringProperty firstName;
    private final StringProperty lastName;
    private final StringProperty gender;
    private final IntegerProperty familyID;
    private final IntegerProperty personID;
    private final StringProperty toolTipText;
    private final Tooltip toolTip;


    public APerson() {
        this(null, null, null, 0, 0 );
    }

    /**
     * Constructor with some initial data.
     *
     * @param familyID
     * @param personID
     * @param firstName
     * @param lastName
     * @param gender
     */
    public APerson( String firstName, String lastName, String gender, int familyID, int personID) {
        this.firstName = new SimpleStringProperty(firstName);
        this.lastName = new SimpleStringProperty(lastName);
        this.gender = new SimpleStringProperty(gender);
        this.familyID = new SimpleIntegerProperty(familyID);
        this.personID = new SimpleIntegerProperty(personID);
        this.toolTipText = new SimpleStringProperty(null);
        this.toolTip = new Tooltip();
    }
//    

    public int getFamilyID() {
        return familyID.get();
    }

    public void setFamilyID(int FamilyID) {
        this.familyID.set(FamilyID);
    }

    public IntegerProperty familyIDProperty() {
        return familyID;
    }
//    

    public int getPersonID() {
        return personID.get();
    }

    public void setPersonID(int PersonID) {
        this.personID.set(PersonID);
    }

    public IntegerProperty personIDProperty() {
        return personID;
    }
//    

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName.get().trim();
    }

    public void setFirstName(String FirstName) {
        this.firstName.set(FirstName);
    }

    public StringProperty firstNameProperty() {
        return firstName;
    }
//

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName.get();
    }

    public void setLastName(String LastName) {
        this.lastName.set(LastName);
    }

    public StringProperty lastNameProperty() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public String getGender() {
        return gender.get();
    }

    public void setGender(String Gender) {
        this.gender.set(Gender);
    }

    public StringProperty genderProperty() {
        return gender;
    }

    public String LoadToolTipText() {
        String tmp = "";
        String headerLine = "<body style=\"background-color: LavenderBlush; border-style: none;\"> <u><b><font color=\"red\">Click Mouse's right button to see options</font></b></u><br><br>";
        headerLine = headerLine+"<font color=\"red\">Use ARROW keys to scrol the Tooltip</font></b></u><br><br>";
        Text t1 = new Text();
        t1.setText(headerLine);

        String ToolTipText = t1.getText() +  this.toString() + "<br>";


        ToolTipText = ToolTipText + "<br></body>";
        this.toolTip.setStyle("-fx-background-color: pink; -fx-text-fill: black;  -fx-font: normal normal 12pt \"Times New Roman\"");

        this.toolTip.setText(ToolTipText);

//        System.out.println("Tip: "+ToolTipText);

        return ToolTipText;
    }

    public Tooltip getToolTip() {
        // A browser.
        return toolTip;
    }

  //
    public String toString() {
        String tmp =  this.getFirstName() + " " + this.getLastName() + " [" + this.getPersonID()+"] ";
        return tmp;
    }
}
```

Main.java

```
package application;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;


public class Main extends Application {

    test000Controller myController;

    static private javafx.collections.ObservableList<APerson> persons = javafx.collections.FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    static private javafx.collections.ObservableList<APerson> fathers = javafx.collections.FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    static private javafx.collections.ObservableList<APerson> mothers = javafx.collections.FXCollections.observableArrayList();


    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {

        loadFathers();

        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("test000.fxml"));
        Parent root = (Parent) loader.load();
        myController =  loader.getController();
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);

        myController.persons = persons;
        myController.fathers = fathers;
        myController.mothers = mothers;

        myController.setCBValues();

        stage.setTitle("Check editable Combo - TEST000");
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    private void loadFathers() {
        persons.clear();
        persons.add(new APerson("*** Not ", "Known ***","F" ,2,0));
        persons.add(new APerson("Nesammal", "Rivington","F" ,2,57));
        persons.add(new APerson("Ratnammal","Andews","F",1,55));
        persons.add(new APerson("Hornigold","Arthur","M", 1,63));
        persons.add(new APerson("Andrews","Sundareson","M", 2,60));
        persons.add(new APerson("Christopher","Easweradoss","M", 3,57));
        persons.add(new APerson("Arthur","Kennedy","M", 4,55));
        persons.add(new APerson("Victoria","Arthur","F" , 1,95));
        persons.add(new APerson("Eliza", "Daniel","F", 1,60));

        fathers.clear();
        fathers.add(new APerson("*** Not ", "Known ***","F" ,2,0));
        fathers.add(new APerson("Hornigold","Arthur","M", 1,63));
        fathers.add(new APerson("Andrews","Sundareson","M", 2,60));
        fathers.add(new APerson("Christopher","Easweradoss","M", 3,57));
        fathers.add(new APerson("Arthur","Kennedy","M", 4,55));

        mothers.clear();
        mothers.add(new APerson("*** Not ", "Known ***","F" ,2,0));
        mothers.add(new APerson("Nesammal", "Rivington","F" ,2,57));
        mothers.add(new APerson("Ratnammal","Andews","F",1,55));
        mothers.add(new APerson("Victoria","Arthur","F" , 1,95));
        mothers.add(new APerson("Eliza", "Daniel","F", 1,60));

    }


}
```

test000.fxml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.ComboBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextField?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.HBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Font?>

<AnchorPane prefHeight="502.0" prefWidth="325.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/10.0.1" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="application.test000Controller">
   <children>
      <VBox prefHeight="431.0" prefWidth="301.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="10.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="10.0">
         <children>
            <Label text="Fathers : ">
               <font>
                  <Font name="Times New Roman Bold" size="12.0" />
               </font>
            </Label>
            <ComboBox fx:id="cbFather" editable="true" onAction="#onCBFather" prefHeight="35.0" prefWidth="325.0" promptText="Enter search string" stylesheets="@application.css">
               <VBox.margin>
                  <Insets top="5.0" />
               </VBox.margin></ComboBox>
            <TextField fx:id="txtValue" editable="false" prefHeight="38.0" prefWidth="301.0" promptText="Selected value" style="-fx-background-color: white; -fx-border-color: red;">
               <VBox.margin>
                  <Insets top="15.0" />
               </VBox.margin>
            </TextField>
            <Label text="Mothers : ">
               <font>
                  <Font name="Times New Roman Bold" size="12.0" />
               </font>
               <VBox.margin>
                  <Insets top="5.0" />
               </VBox.margin>
            </Label>
            <ComboBox fx:id="cbMother" editable="true" onAction="#onCBMother" prefHeight="35.0" prefWidth="325.0" promptText="Enter search string" stylesheets="@application.css">
               <VBox.margin>
                  <Insets top="5.0" />
               </VBox.margin>
            </ComboBox>
            <Label text="Spouses : ">
               <font>
                  <Font name="Times New Roman Bold" size="12.0" />
               </font>
               <VBox.margin>
                  <Insets top="5.0" />
               </VBox.margin>
            </Label>
            <ComboBox fx:id="cbSpouse" editable="true" prefHeight="35.0" prefWidth="325.0" promptText="Enter search string" stylesheets="@application.css">
               <VBox.margin>
                  <Insets top="5.0" />
               </VBox.margin>
            </ComboBox>
            <Label text="Gender:">
               <font>
                  <Font name="Times New Roman Bold" size="12.0" />
               </font>
               <VBox.margin>
                  <Insets top="5.0" />
               </VBox.margin>
            </Label>
            <ComboBox fx:id="cbGender" editable="true" onAction="#onCBGender" onMouseClicked="#handleGenderMoouseEvent" prefHeight="35.0" prefWidth="325.0" promptText="Select Gender" stylesheets="@application.css">
               <VBox.margin>
                  <Insets top="5.0" />
               </VBox.margin>
            </ComboBox>
         </children>
      </VBox>
      <HBox layoutX="14.0" layoutY="450.0" prefHeight="38.0" prefWidth="294.0">
         <children>
            <Button fx:id="btnCB1" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#showCB1Value" prefHeight="41.0" prefWidth="123.0" text="CB1 value">
               <font>
                  <Font name="System Bold" size="14.0" />
               </font>
            </Button>
            <Button fx:id="btnCB2" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#showCB2Value" prefHeight="41.0" prefWidth="123.0" text="CB2 value">
               <font>
                  <Font name="System Bold" size="14.0" />
               </font>
               <HBox.margin>
                  <Insets left="25.0" />
               </HBox.margin>
            </Button>
         </children>
      </HBox>
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

test000Controller.java

```
package application;

import application.APerson;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.ChoiceBox;
import javafx.scene.control.ComboBox;
import javafx.scene.control.ContentDisplay;
import javafx.scene.control.ListCell;
import javafx.scene.control.ListView;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.control.Tooltip;
import javafx.scene.input.InputMethodEvent;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyCode;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyEvent;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.scene.web.WebEngine;
import javafx.scene.web.WebView;
import javafx.util.Callback;
import javafx.util.StringConverter;

public class test000Controller {

    boolean searchWordStartOnly = true;
    private ObservableList<APerson> originalData;
    private ObservableList<APerson> originalData2;
    public javafx.collections.ObservableList<APerson> persons;
    public javafx.collections.ObservableList<APerson> fathers;
    public javafx.collections.ObservableList<APerson> mothers;

    @FXML
    private ResourceBundle resources;

    @FXML
    private URL location;

    @FXML
    private ComboBox<APerson> cbFather;

    @FXML
    private ComboBox<APerson> cbMother;

    @FXML
    private ComboBox<APerson> cbSpouse;

    @FXML
    private ComboBox<String> cbGender;

    @FXML
    private TextField txtValue;

    @FXML
    private Button btnCB1;

    @FXML
    private Button btnCB2;

    @FXML
    void onCBFather(ActionEvent event) {
        if (event.getEventType().toString() != null) {
            System.out.println("ActionEvent - CBFather - Fired = "+event.getEventType().toString());

        }
    }

    @FXML
    void onCBMother(ActionEvent event) {
        if (event.getEventType().toString() != null) {
            System.out.println("ActionEvent - CBMother - Fired = "+event.getEventType().toString());

        }
    }

    @FXML
    void showCB1Value(ActionEvent event) {
        txtValue.setText("Button 1 was clicked - "+cbFather.getValue());
    }

    @FXML
    void showCB2Value(ActionEvent event) {
        txtValue.setText("Button 2 was clicked - "+cbMother.getValue());
    }

    @FXML
    void onCBGender(ActionEvent event) {
//      event.fireEvent(arg0, arg1);
        cbGender.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener((options, oldValue, newValue) -> {
            System.out.println("cbGender newValue -> " + newValue);
        });
    }

    @FXML
    void handleGenderMoouseEvent(MouseEvent event) {

        System.out.println("This is MOUSE CLICKED on cbGENDER");

    }


    @FXML
    void initialize() {
        assert cbFather != null : "fx:id=\"cbFather\" was not injected: check your FXML file 'test000.fxml'.";
        assert txtValue != null : "fx:id=\"txtValue\" was not injected: check your FXML file 'test000.fxml'.";
        assert cbMother != null : "fx:id=\"cbMother\" was not injected: check your FXML file 'test000.fxml'.";
        assert cbSpouse != null : "fx:id=\"cbSpouse\" was not injected: check your FXML file 'test000.fxml'.";
        assert btnCB1 != null : "fx:id=\"btnCB1\" was not injected: check your FXML file 'test000.fxml'.";
        assert btnCB2 != null : "fx:id=\"btnCB2\" was not injected: check your FXML file 'test000.fxml'.";
        assert cbGender != null : "fx:id=\"cbGender\" was not injected: check your FXML file 'test000.fxml'.";

    }

    public void setCBValues() {


        cbGender.valueProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<String>() {
        @Override 
        public void changed(ObservableValue ov, String t, String t1) {
            System.out.println("Change Listener for cbGender - oldValue "+t+" new value"+t1);
            if ((t1.equals("Male")) || (t.equals(null))) {
                cbSpouse.setItems(mothers);
            } else {
                cbSpouse.setItems(fathers);
            }
            cbSpouse.getSelectionModel().selectFirst();
        }    
    });
//
        ObservableList<String> GenderOptions = FXCollections.observableArrayList("Male", "Female");
        cbGender.setItems(GenderOptions);
        cbGender.setValue("Male");

        createCBFather(persons);
        createCBMother(persons);
    }

    public void createCBFather(javafx.collections.ObservableList<APerson> persons) {

        cbFather.getItems().clear();
        cbFather.setItems(persons);
        cbFather.setEditable(true);
        cbFather.setMaxWidth(Double.MAX_VALUE);
        cbFather.setVisibleRowCount(5);
        originalData = cbFather.getItems();

        cbFather.getEditor().setOnMousePressed(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {    
             @Override
             public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
                if (cbFather.getEditor().getText() == null) {
                    cbFather.getItems().clear();
                    cbFather.setItems(persons);
                    cbFather.setEditable(true);
                    cbFather.setMaxWidth(Double.MAX_VALUE);
                    cbFather.setVisibleRowCount(5);
                }
                System.out.println("MOUSE PRESSED!!! in EDITOR");
             }
        });
//      
        cbFather.setOnMouseClicked(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {    
             @Override
             public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
                if (cbFather.getEditor().getText() == null) {
                    cbFather.getItems().clear();
                    cbFather.setItems(persons);
                    cbFather.setEditable(true);
                    cbFather.setMaxWidth(Double.MAX_VALUE);
                    cbFather.setVisibleRowCount(5);
                }
                System.out.println("MOUSE PRESSED!!! in CB BUTTON");
             }
        });
//      
        cbFather.getSelectionModel().selectFirst();
//
        cbFather.setConverter(new CBFatherConverter());
//
        setCellFactory(cbFather);
//      
        handleKeyPressed(cbFather, originalData);

        cbFather.valueProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<APerson>() {
            @Override 
            public void changed(ObservableValue ov, APerson t, APerson t1) {
                System.out.println("Change Listener for cbFather - ov "+t+" new value"+t1);
                if (t1 == null) {
                    cbFather.setItems(persons);
//                  cbFather.getSelectionModel().selectFirst();;
                }
            }    
        });


    }

    class  CBFatherConverter extends StringConverter<APerson> {

        @Override
        public String toString(APerson object) {
            if (object == null) {
                cbFather.setPromptText("Use Arrow Keys or type to locate entry");
                return null;
            }
            return object.toString();
        }

        @Override
        public APerson fromString(String thisString) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            for (APerson pers : cbFather.getItems()) {
                if (pers.toString().equals(thisString)) {
                    APerson person = pers;
                    return person;
                }
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
//
    public void createCBMother(javafx.collections.ObservableList<APerson> persons) {

        cbMother.setItems(persons);
        cbMother.setEditable(true);
        cbMother.setMaxWidth(Double.MAX_VALUE);
        cbMother.setVisibleRowCount(5);
        originalData2 = cbMother.getItems();

        cbMother.getSelectionModel().selectFirst();

//        if (cbGender.getValue().equals("Male")) {
//          cbSpouse.setItems(mothers);
//        } else {
//          cbSpouse.setItems(fathers);
//        }
//
        cbMother.setConverter(new CBMotherConverter());
//
        setCellFactory(cbMother);
//      
        handleKeyPressed(cbMother, originalData2);

//      cbMother.valueProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<APerson>() {
//          @Override 
//          public void changed(ObservableValue ov, APerson t, APerson t1) {
//              System.out.println("Change Listener for cbMother - ov "+t+" new value"+t1);
//          }    
//      });
//
//      cbGender.setValue("Male");
//      
    }
//
    class CBMotherConverter extends StringConverter<APerson> {

        @Override
        public String toString(APerson object) {
            if (object == null) {
                cbMother.setPromptText("Use Arrorw Keys or type to locate entry");
                return null;
            }
            return object.toString();
        }

        @Override
        public APerson fromString(String thisString) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            for (APerson pers : cbMother.getItems()) {
                if (pers.toString().equals(thisString)) {
                    APerson person = pers;
                    return person;
                }
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
//
    public void setCellFactory(ComboBox<APerson> thisCombo) {

        thisCombo.setCellFactory(new Callback<ListView<APerson>, ListCell<APerson>>() {
            @Override
            public ListCell<APerson> call(ListView<APerson> param) {
                final ListCell<APerson> cell = new ListCell<APerson>() {
                    @Override
                    protected void updateItem(APerson item, boolean empty) {
                        super.updateItem(item, empty);
                        if (item != null) {
                            final ListCell<APerson> this$ = this;
                            item.LoadToolTipText();
                            String htmlString = item.getToolTip().getText();
                            Tooltip.install(this$, createToolTip(htmlString));
                            String str = item.toString();
                            setText(str);

                            if (item.getGender() == "M") {
                                String cellStyle = "    -fx-font-size: 16;\n"
                                        + "    -fx-font-family: \"Times New Roman\";\n" + "-fx-text-fill: blue;";
                                setStyle(cellStyle);
                            } else {
                                String cellStyle = "    -fx-font-size: 16;\n"
                                        + "    -fx-font-family: \"Times New Roman\";\n" + "-fx-text-fill: red;";
                                setStyle(cellStyle);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }; // ListCell
                return cell;
            }
        }); // setCellFactory

    }

    public void handleKeyPressed(ComboBox<APerson> thisCombo, ObservableList<APerson> originalData) {

        thisCombo.addEventHandler(KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED, t -> thisCombo.hide());
        thisCombo.addEventFilter(KeyEvent.KEY_RELEASED, new EventHandler<KeyEvent>() {

            private boolean moveCaretToPos = false;
            private int caretPos;

            @Override
            public void handle(KeyEvent event) {

                switch (event.getCode()) {
                case UP:
                    if (thisCombo.getEditor().equals(null)) {
                        thisCombo.getSelectionModel().selectFirst();
                        thisCombo.show();
                    }
                    break;
                //
                case DOWN:

                    System.out.println("Processing DOWN arrow");
                    if (thisCombo.getEditor().equals(null)) {
                        System.out.println("Editor is NULL");
                        thisCombo.getSelectionModel().selectFirst();
                        thisCombo.show();
                    }

                    if (!thisCombo.isShowing()) {
                        if (thisCombo.getItems().size() == 0) {
                            System.out.println("Processing DOWN arrow - Combo Box is EMPTY");
                            thisCombo.setItems(originalData);
                        } else {
                            System.out.println("Processing DOWN arrow - Has items.");
                        }
                        thisCombo.getSelectionModel().selectFirst();
                        thisCombo.show();
                    }

                    break;
                //
                case BACK_SPACE:
                    moveCaretToPos = true;
                    caretPos = thisCombo.getEditor().getCaretPosition();
                    break;
                //
                case DELETE:
                    moveCaretToPos = true;
                    caretPos = thisCombo.getEditor().getCaretPosition();
                    break;
                case ENTER:
                    break;
                //

                case RIGHT:
                case LEFT:
                case SHIFT:
                case HOME:
                case END:
                case TAB:
                case CONTROL:

                    return;

                default:

                    if (event.getCode().ALPHANUMERIC != null) {
//                      System.out.println("in ALPHANUMERIC input");
                        locateItems();
                    }

                    break;

                }

                APerson waste = (APerson) getComboBoxValue(thisCombo);
                if (waste != null) {
                    txtValue.setText(waste.getFirstName()+" ID = "+waste.getPersonID());
                } else {
                    txtValue.setText("");
                }
            }

            private void locateItems() {
                txtValue.setText("Alpha numeric input");
                ObservableList<APerson> list = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
                int selectedIndex = 0;
                for (APerson aData : originalData) {
                    String tmp = thisCombo.getEditor().getText().toLowerCase();

                    if (checkMatch(thisCombo, aData, tmp)) {
                        list.add(aData);
                        selectedIndex++;
                    }
                }

                String t = thisCombo.getEditor().getText();

                thisCombo.setItems(list);
                thisCombo.getEditor().setText(t);
                if (!moveCaretToPos) {
                    caretPos = -1;
                }
                moveCaret(t.length());
                if (!list.isEmpty()) {
                    thisCombo.hide();
                    if (list.size() > 5) {
                        thisCombo.setVisibleRowCount(5);
                    } else {
                        thisCombo.setVisibleRowCount(list.size());
                    }
                    thisCombo.getSelectionModel().select(selectedIndex);
                    thisCombo.show();
                }

            }

            private void moveCaret(int textLength) {
                if (caretPos == -1) {
                    thisCombo.getEditor().positionCaret(textLength);
                } else {
                    thisCombo.getEditor().positionCaret(caretPos);
                }
                moveCaretToPos = false;
            }
        });

    }

    private boolean checkMatch(ComboBox thisCombo, APerson aData, String tmp) {
        boolean retValue = false;

        if (aData != null && thisCombo.getEditor().getText() != null) {
            String[] words = aData.toString().split(" ");
            for (String thisWord : words) {
                if (searchWordStartOnly) {
                    if (thisWord.toLowerCase().startsWith(tmp)) {
                        return true;
                    }
                } else {
                    if (thisWord.toLowerCase().contains(tmp)) {
                        return true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return retValue;
    }

    public Object getComboBoxValue(ComboBox thisCombo) {
        System.out.println("getComboBoxValue - name = "+thisCombo.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem());
        if (thisCombo.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex() < 0) {
            return null;
        } else {
        System.out.println("Item Selected in cbFather is = "+thisCombo.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem());
            return thisCombo.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
        }

    }
//
    private Tooltip createToolTip(String htmlStr) {
        Tooltip thisToolTip = new Tooltip();

        WebView browser = new WebView();
        WebEngine webEngine = browser.getEngine();
        webEngine.loadContent(htmlStr);

        thisToolTip.setStyle("\n" + "    -fx-border-color: black;\n" + "    -fx-border-width: 1px;\n"
                + "    -fx-font: normal bold 12pt \"Times New Roman\" ;\n"
                + "    -fx-background-color: LavenderBlush;\n" + "    -fx-text-fill: black;\n"
                + "    -fx-background-radius: 4;\n" + "    -fx-border-radius: 4;\n" + "    -fx-opacity: 1.0;");

        thisToolTip.setContentDisplay(ContentDisplay.GRAPHIC_ONLY);

        thisToolTip.setGraphic(browser);
        thisToolTip.setAutoHide(false);
        thisToolTip.setMaxWidth(300);
        thisToolTip.setPrefHeight(400);
        thisToolTip.setGraphicTextGap(0.0);

        return thisToolTip;
    }


}
```

In this example data is Hard coded and in Main.java, but in the other version, it is loaded from
    static private javafx.collections.ObservableList Fathers = javafx.collections.FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    static private javafx.collections.ObservableList Mothers = javafx.collections.FXCollections.observableArrayList();

loading the ObservableList from database occurs much earlier, before cbGender valueProperty Changed.

Thanks,

Comment: this is not an answer, right? Please edit your question to add additional details .. and a) make it an example that _does_ show the problem b) strip it down (50 to 100 lines of code are enough) to comply to the "M" = minimal

Comment: Forget it, even the combo box in Eclipse works that way. Check "Find String" when the number of strings increase, that also takes time to show the list of strings which you have already searched for, after you click in the drop down button.